# Can't change Libreoffice Base from dark mode

Tags: color-theme, background, macos-ventura, libreoffice-base

I am running Libreoffice 7.5.4.2 in a Mac Mini with an M1 chip.  I used to run LibreOffice 7.3.1.3 on the same computer.  When I opened my databases on 7.3.1.3, they opened all with a gray background, including the frame around the database with the various icon for New, Open, Save, etc.  Now, under 7.5.4.2, the frame is black and the subform is also black.  I have gone into preferences and looked under application colors.  It says "LibreOffice." Underneath, but not applied, is "LibreOffice Dark"  How can I get a light background on everything?

Answer (score 1):

This is from a **Windows machine**; the menus might be the same on Mac.

1. Click on Tools -> Options
2. On the left pane, Select View.
3. Set mode to `Light`. Click <kbd>Apply</kbd>. Click <kbd>OK</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: This seems to have done the trick!  The Mac OS layout isn't quite the same, but there is View and the ability to chance appearance from System to Light.  Thanks again!

Comment: @FWS See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers).